# Scaling HTML/CSS to fit various monitors, is it possible?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I know SVG supports this. But I'm wondering if HTML/CSS can be scaled up and down, like an image to fit various monitors? For example, think an HTML5 phonegap based mobile app that just "works" on many of the different sized screens from iPhone (3,4s,5,etc), android, etc and the multitude of screen sizes out there.

I'm not talking about using percentage widths, like 100%, or 20% within the divs, em for fonts, or a bunch of media queries. I'd like to use absolute width/heights on my divs because it's easier to program.

So for example, let's say I create an app that's 400px width, and 600px height and everything within that div (buttons, more divs, images, etc) also uses pixel heights and widths and positioning.

Now, is there a way to just "scale" this thing to any resolution I want like an image? Kind of just like surrounding it by

```
<scaleToDevice>
<div style='width:400px;height:600px'>
    ... All my other UI here, like buttons, etc would use absolute positioning with pixels
</div>
</scaleToDevice>
```

and it'd "just work" think of like how you scale an image in Photoshop. Except this would just be on HTML/CSS, scale to the device's 100% width and height, and the app would remain interactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's possible, you'll need to use the [**CSS transform**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property. However, keep in mind you'll need some maths to do, because you'll need to keep in mind orientation as well as screens' aspect ratio. But well, if you want to do it, you can do it. Here's some code I gave to another user that you can use as a starting point:

```
#body {
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    text-align:center;
}
#content {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
    top:50%;
    transform: scale(2);
    transform-origin: 0%;
}
```

This will also make the scale of element grow from center (which will look better for example on mobiles if you're rotating views. You may also add transitions for smoother effects). So go ahead, try it. But there's a reason why nobody else doesn't do it: the effort isn't worth the final result, you'll end always needing a fine tuning

Comment: yeah.. this does seem like an "alternative" solution esp with css transforms. I guess the majority just uses percent divs and media queries to fit various devices?

Comment: this is not the "alternative", this is probably the only way to do what you want as you stated it. Otherwise, we're talking about regular auto-adjusting elements, whether you use percentages (doesn't work for fonts) or like using viewport sizes, which you can use with fonts. You can also use jQuery solutions as well, but as fas as your question goes, I don't think you can go much further than CSS transforms and viewport sizes

Comment: thank you. there's another thing I've been seeing alot, something with <meta name="viewport" ..> or other, I'm still researching if it can solve my problem

Comment: yes, viewport is the main part of a responsive design, it's basically the size of the visible part of the device's screen. You can see some info at http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/ or a bit more technical at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag . Thus, viewport sizes as I mentioned above are vh and vw, which mean vh=viewport height = the height of the visible part of the screen (in other words: the browser screen in any resized or not state) . VW stands for viewport width

Comment: I ended up just creating a fixed width (pixel) based UI, and transforming it to the physical screen size. works good for now.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at using CSS viewport width/height (vw/vh) properties.

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

This way you can base all your width/height/sizes (in CSS) off these vw, vh properties, and with the correct math you entire site can scale up and down with the resizing of the window.

Comment: this is interesting I'll look more into this.